# How to save DTS package on windows with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dts

I installed SQL Server 2008 standard on windows 7.
Then I can run legacy DTS package wizard from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe.

I tried to export for this case. At the end of the wizard, I want to save DTS package but I got message as:

In SQL Server Express, Web, or Workgroup, you can run the package that the Import and Export Wizard creates, but cannot save it. To save packages that the wizard creates, you must upgrade to SQL Server Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation.

Actually I already install SQL Server 2008 Standard. Not sure why still get this message and I can't save it.

How to save the DTS package for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Just use your sql server installation to install Management Studio and/or (sorry, I don't remember which one actually solved the problem) BIDS tools for Visual Studio and you'll be fine. You need to start off like you were installing new isntance of Sql Server, but then choose "Additional Features / Tools" (or something like that).